# In a function, Is there a way to return user input along with result?

Tags: javascript

/*fahr is the user input which then converts it to celc and vise versa. */

```
function convc(fahr){
        var m = fahr
        return (m-32) * (5/9)
    
};
function convf(celc){
    return (celc * 9/5) + 32;
};

const a = convf(50);
console.log(`${m} is ${a} degrees in celcius`)
```

Comment: Sure, return an object with both input and result.

Comment: But… why? You already know what you passed in, you'd just need to store it in a variable.

Comment: following @404 comment, try  `return { c:celc, f:(celc*9/5)+32 }`